# Store Post along with user id, referenced to User table in Laravel 6

Tags: php, eloquent, model, relationship, laravel-6

I have Post and User Model with relationship as follows:
`user_id` is the foreign key in `posts` table referenced to the `id` of the `users` table

## Post Model

```
public function user () {
  return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'user_id','id');
}
```

## User Model

```
public function posts () {
  return $this->hasMany(Posts::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

And a `PostController` with store method:

```
public function store(Request $request){
 $this->validate($request, [
  'title' => 'required|max:255',
  'desc' => 'required|max:255'
 ]);

 $image = null;
 $files = $request->thumbnail;
 $thumb = time().'.'.$files->getClientOriginalExtension();
 $request->thumbnail->move(public_path('public'),$thumb);
 $image = $thumb;
 $post = Posts::create([
   'title' => $request->title,
   'thumbnail' => $image,
   'user_id' => __________
   'desc' => $request->desc
 ]);
 return $post->toJson();                     }
```

Considering that, I want to acheive a relationship as: a user can have many posts.
So, how can I get the `id` of the `user` with the help of relationship between `users` and `posts` table to insert in the posts table. 
Edit: in above controller how can I get user_id value??

Comment: return User::with('posts')->where('id',$id)->get()

Comment: Sorry, I think I didn't mentioned that, I need to get the user_id to store in the posts table. I have edited the question

Comment: 'user_id' => Auth::user()->id;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's very easy.

you can get id by url:

```
localhost:8000/users/{id}
```

In your route [web.php]

```
Route::get('/users/{id}', 'UserController@show');
```

Your Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;


class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function show($id)
    {
        return User::with('posts')->where('id',$id)->get()
    }
```

**Question Updated so answer must to update:**

after login you should use below code:

You will access the authenticated user via the Auth facade:

```
// Get the currently authenticated user...
$user = Auth::user();

// Get the currently authenticated user's ID...
$id = Auth::id();
```

Dont forget the namespace

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```